# Basic Currency Converter

Tags: c++

I am a beginner coder and I have a problem with my code. Every time I run it, near the end it always goes to the else statement. I tried including break statements to see if that would help, but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried just making all of them if statements instead of using else if.
This code was written in C++ .
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{

public:
    int num;

    void number()
    {
        cout << "1 for British Pound " << endl;
        cout << "2 for Mexican Pesos " << endl;
        cout << "3 for Japanese Yen " << endl;
        cout << "4 for Chinese Yen " << endl;
        cout << "5 for Australian Dollar "
             << "\n\n";
        cout << "Enter number here: ";
        cin >> num;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    float money;
    float res;

public:
    void ifs()
    {
        number();

        if (num == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter how much US money you have:  ";
            cin >> money;
            res = money * 0.77; // British pound is 0.77 for every US dollar.
            cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in British pounds";
        }

        if (num == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter how much US money you have:  ";
            cin >> money;
            res = money * 20.08; // Mexican Pesos is 20.08 for every US dollar.
            cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in Mexican Pesos. ";
        }
    }
};

class C : public B
{
private:
    float money, res;

public:
    void ifs2()
    {
        ifs();
        if (num == 3)
        {
            cout << "Enter how much US money you have:  ";
            cin >> money;
            res = money * 125.31; // Japansese Yen is 125.31 for every US dollar.
            cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in Japanese Yen. ";
        }

        if (num == 4)
        {
            cout << "Enter how much US money you have:  ";
            cin >> money;
            res = money * 6.37; // Chinese Yen is 6.37 for every US dollar.
            cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in Chinese Yen. ";
        }

        if (num == 5)
        {
            cout << "Enter how much US money you have: ";
            cin >> money;
            res = money * 1.35; // Australian Dollar is 1.35 for every US dollar.
            cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in Australian Dollar. ";
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number that is listed above! ";
        };
    }
};

int main()
{
    C obj;
    obj.ifs2();
}

// This code is a US currency converter.

// It contains class and methods.
```

Comment: When `if(num==3)` is true, then it will enter the `else` of `if (num==5)`. Did you mean `else if (num==5)` etc?

Comment: Before I changed it, it was already that and I was still getting the same results.

Comment: even with that fix, you're ignoring the fact that `ifs()` my have already handled the data in the cases of (1) and (2). You never communicate that back to the call-point, so you blindly march into if(3) else if(4) else if (5) **else**. You need to convey *back* to the call point in `ifs2` whether `ifs` did anything constructive, and if so, basically do *nothing* else in `ifs2` and just leave the function.

Comment: It's not a good idea to represent currency using a floating point type, because all floating point types with a binary mantissa (which includes most real-world floating point representations) cannot represent values like `0.1` or `0.3` exactly.  Money amounts are usually expressed using major and minor parts (e.g. dollars and cents, pound and pence) so CANNOT be accurately represented using floating point.   Operations on floating point (e.g. adding or multiplying amounts) propagates error, which is bad news for money calcs. Use a pair of integers instead, and implement appropriate operations.

Comment: You have a lot of code duplication. In every block you repeat all lines of code with only a single value and a peace of text is different. You should make it a function/method! If you split execution for value 1+2 and for 3-5 in different functions, the first have give back a value which can be evaluated in the second part of comparison, because you have to know if the value was already handled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a control statement between multiple conditions, you have to use `else if`. When using `else if`, it will sequentially evaluate the `if` conditions. Currently, the `else` only works for the last `if (num == 5)`.

The correct answer would be:

```
public:
    void ifs2()
    {
        ifs();
        if (num == 3)
        {
            cout << "Enter how much US money you have:  ";
            cin >> money;
            res = money * 125.31; // Japansese Yen is 125.31 for every US dollar.
            cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in Japanese Yen. ";
        }

        else if (num == 4)
        {
            cout << "Enter how much US money you have:  ";
            cin >> money;
            res = money * 6.37; // Chinese Yen is 6.37 for every US dollar.
            cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in Chinese Yen. ";
        }

        else if (num == 5)
        {
            cout << "Enter how much US money you have: ";
            cin >> money;
            res = money * 1.35; // Australian Dollar is 1.35 for every US dollar.
            cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in Australian Dollar. ";
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number that is listed above! ";
        };
    }
};

int main()
{
    C obj;
    obj.ifs2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you're always re-evaluating your `num` input.

If you want to use if-statements, consider using if/else constructs:

```cpp
void MyClass::foo() {
    if (num == 1) {

    } else if (num == 2) {

    } /*...*/ {

    } else {
        // handle other cases here
    }
}
```

The more suitable approach, however, is to use a switch/case construct here.
It's similar to if/else in the way it works, but offers cleaner code and more performance.

```
void MyClass::foo() {
    switch (num) {
        case 1: // handle first case
            break;
        case 2: // handle second case
            break;
        // add more cases as needed
        default: // this would be your "else" block
             break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (num == 5)
    {
        cout << "Enter how much US money you have: ";
        cin >> money;
        res = money * 1.35; // Australian Dollar is 1.35 for every US dollar.
        cout << money << "$ in US is " << res << " in Australian Dollar. ";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number that is listed above! ";
    };
```

This else branch is connected to if statement "num == 5". Compiler reads code line by line. It reads first if then second then third. If first if statement is true or not still it goes to next statement. Meanwhile if you enter number other than 5 then it will go to this else statement. If you test this program with number 5 it will work fine. Otherwise it will show this else message. Use if else if instead or switch case to remove ambiguity or re evaluation.